# tensorflow ValueError: scan/while/Merge_1:0

Tags: python, tensorflow, while-loop, deep-learning, shapes

how can i fix this error..
i don't know why this error occurred.. this error blocked me for two days

Sigh..

> ValueError: The shape for my_cost_value/scan/while/Merge_1:0 is not an
>   invariant for the loop. It enters the loop with shape (), but has
>   shape  after one iteration. Provide shape invariants using
>   either the `shape_invariants` argument of tf.while_loop or set_shape()
>   on the loop variables

below is my code

```
    ################# constant
    bach_size = 100
    layers = 1
    directions = 1
    hiddensize = 100
    self.hiddensize = hiddensize
    self.def_output_length = 2
    self.enc = encoder
    input_length = 484
    teacher_forcing = False
    with tf.variable_scope('self_outputinit') as scope:
        self.output_ini = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, self.hiddensize]),dtype='float32') #my output segment

    ################# training val
    with tf.variable_scope('decoder_var') as scope:
        self.W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.hiddensize*2, input_length]), dtype='float32')
        self.W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([self.hiddensize*2, self.hiddensize]), dtype='float32')
        self.b1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, input_length]), dtype='float32')
        self.b2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1, self.hiddensize]), dtype='float32')

    with tf.variable_scope("mygru") as scope:
        self.gru = tf.nn.rnn_cell.GRUCell(num_units = 100)



    ###################  inputs
    with tf.variable_scope('encoder_output') as scope:# shape = (100,484,100)
        self.input_v = encoder.getoutput()

    with tf.variable_scope('realsent') as scope: # shape = (100,seq,100)
        self.realsent = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32')

    with tf.variable_scope('decoder_res_seq') as scope: # shape = (100,seq)
        self.output_length = tf.placeholder(dtype='float32')

    with tf.variable_scope('encoder_state') as scope: #shape = (100,100)
        self.grustate = encoder.getstate()
        self.grustate = tf.reshape(self.grustate,shape=(100,1,100))



    ################## input concat ====>> (100,4) .. 4 = (484,100) + (seq,100) + seq + 100
    #with tf.variable_scope('concat_cost_input') as scope:
    #    self.concat_input = tf.stack([self.input_v,self.realsent,self.output_length,self.grustate],axis=1)

    ################## cost cal
    with tf.variable_scope('my_cost_value') as scope:
        #self.cost = tf.Variable(0.0,dtype="float32")
        newar = np.array([],dtype="float32")
        for i in range(100):
            newar = np.append(newar,i)

        self.lastcost = tf.scan(self._bach_calcost, newar.astype("float32"))









    ################## training
    with tf.variable_scope('adamtrain') as scope:
        self.adamtrain = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1).minimize(self.lastcost)

    with tf.variable_scope('gradtrain') as scope:
        self.gradtrain = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=10).minimize(self.lastcost)

    with tf.variable_scope('gradtrain') as scope:
        self.gradtrain2 = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.01).minimize(self.lastcost)

    self.input_seg_v = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(shape=(484,100)),dtype="float32")





    ################## for scan func in _bach_calcost
def _nt_atten(self, grustate_output ,ignore): #not teacher forcing

    with tf.variable_scope("split") as scope:
        pre_new_grustate, pre_new_output = tf.split(grustate_output, num_or_size_splits=2, axis=1)
        _ = ignore

    with tf.variable_scope("grucall") as scope:
        new_grustate, new_output =self.gru.call(pre_new_grustate, pre_new_output )

        #word = myprepdata.findwordsfromvec(output.eval())
        #print(word)
        #np_output = myprepdata.findvecfromwords(word)
        #output = tf.Variable(np_output, dtype="float32")

    with tf.variable_scope("atten") as scope:
        attn = tf.concat([new_grustate, new_output],1)#concat and linear
        attn = tf.add(tf.matmul(attn , self.W1),self.b1) # needs W initialize
        attn = tf.nn.softmax(tf.nn.relu(attn))

    with tf.variable_scope("bmm") as scope: #make 1 wordlike 1 484 * 484 100 == 1 100
        bmm = tf.matmul( attn,tf.squeeze(self.input_seg_v)) 

    with tf.variable_scope("comb") as scope:
        attn_com = tf.concat([bmm, self.output],1 ) # 1 100 + 1 100 = 1 200
        attn_com = tf.add(tf.matmul(attn_com,self.W2),self.b2) # 1 200 * 200 100 = 1 100
        self.output = tf.nn.relu(attn_com)

    with tf.variable_scope("concat") as scope:
        grustate_output = tf.concat([new_grustate, new_output],1) # 1 100 + 1 100 = 1 200
        grustate_output = tf.reshape(grustate_output, [1,200], name='grustate_output')

    return grustate_output




    ################# for scan func in __init__
def _bach_calcost(self,coste, conc_input ):

    with tf.variable_scope('decoder_output_segment') as scope:
        self.output = self.output_ini
        newarv = tf.cast(conc_input,tf.int32)

    with tf.variable_scope('split_input') as scope:
        grustate = tf.gather(self.grustate, newarv)
        self.input_seg_v = tf.gather(self.input_v, newarv)
        output_length = tf.gather(self.output_length,newarv)
        realsent = tf.gather(self.realsent, newarv)

    #    (input_v, realsent, output_length, grustate) = conc_input

    with tf.variable_scope('encoder_concat') as scope:
        encoder_output_state = tf.concat([self.output, grustate],1) # 1*100 + 1*100 = 1*200

    with tf.variable_scope('makesent') as scope:
        self.last_status = tf.scan(self._nt_atten, output_length , initializer = encoder_output_state) #my full output

    with tf.variable_scope('sent_postprocess') as scope:
        pre_sentence = tf.squeeze(self.last_status) # 1 3 1 200 -> 3 200
        _ , self.sentence = tf.split(pre_sentence, num_or_size_splits=2, axis = 1) # 3 200 -> ignore(3,100) acc(3,100)

    with tf.variable_scope('calcost') as scope:
        self.precost = (realsent - self.sentence) * (realsent - self.sentence)
        newcost =  tf.reduce_mean(self.precost)

    return newcost



    ################# print bachcost
def calcost(self,sess,realsente,output_length,line): #reduce demention
    return sess.run([self.lastcost],feed_dict = {self.realsent: realsente, self.output_length:output_length,
                                                  self.enc.input:line})


    ################# for training
def adamtraining(self,sess,realsente,output_length,line):
    #summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./testgru")
    writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
    #s = sess.run(summary,feed_dict = {self.realsent: realsente, self.output_length:output_length,
    #                                              self.enc.input:line})
    #writer.add_summary(s,0)

    return sess.run([self.adamtrain],feed_dict = {self.realsent: realsente, self.output_length:output_length,
                                                  self.enc.input:line})

def gradtraining(self,sess,realsente,output_length,line):
    #summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./testgru")
    writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
    #s = sess.run(summary,feed_dict = {self.realsent: realsente, self.output_length:output_length,
    #                                              self.enc.input:line})
    #writer.add_summary(s,0)

    return sess.run([self.gradtrain],feed_dict = {self.realsent: realsente, self.output_length:output_length,
                                                  self.enc.input:line})
def gradtraining2(self,sess,realsente,output_length,line):
    #summary = tf.summary.merge_all()
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("./testgru")
    writer.add_graph(sess.graph)
    #s = sess.run(summary,feed_dict = {self.realsent: realsente, self.output_length:output_length,
    #                                              self.enc.input:line})
    #writer.add_summary(s,0)

    return sess.run([self.gradtrain2],feed_dict = {self.realsent: realsente, self.output_length:output_length,
                                                  self.enc.input:line})


def hidden_init(self,sess):
    return sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a while loop in your code to try pointing out exact issue, but here is the core problem.

When using `tf.while_loop`, you provide a set of tensors as your `loop_vars`. The shapes of these tensors "must not change much" during the execution of the while loop. In usual cases, the shapes will not change at all. If they do, it is likely a sign of a bug - e.g. you accidentally reordered the tensors when outputting them from the `body`.

Advanced user can explicitly specify the `shape_invariants` that they expect for tensors in `loop_vars`. There is a fairly detailed discussion of shape invariants in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop.